# Обрезать часть пути файла

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Очень простой вопрос, но не могу решить.
Как например. в таком пути `D:\Folder1\Folder2\File 1.txt` вырезать все, и оставить только название файла, с учетом того, что могут быть пробелы в названии.
Я в одном месте писал `путь.Split('\\')` и он обрезал все. Но дальше, я обрезаю не строку, а массив. Если правильно выразился.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lvServers.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            file = lvServers.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
            try
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                for (int ee = 0; ee < filePath.Length; ee++)
                {
                    File.Copy(sourcefile[ee], file+  Path.GetFileName(sourcefile[ee]), true);

                    if (File.Exists(res[i]))
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add($"Файл {sourcefile[ee]} доставлен в - " + lvServers.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text); // Вот тут нужно обрезать путь.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add($"Недоставлен - {sourcefile[ee]} в -  " + lvServers.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text);
                    }
                }
            }
```

`sourcefile[ee]` выводит полный путь файла.
Если напишу `sourcefile[ee].Split('\\')` он просто выведет `System.String[]`. В таком случае, вроде, надо дописывать так `sourcefile[ee].Split('\\').Length - 1` Но выводит он не то.

Мы выбрали два файла с названиями Новый 1 и Новый 2 и скопировали их. И в `ListView` Выведется `Файл 2 доставлен....` А куда делся Файл 1 и почему Файл "Новый 2" обрезался до просто "2". Сам обход работает. Если оставить `sourcefile[ee]`, то он выводит два полных, разных пути.

Помогите пожалуйста. Что надо, дополню.

Comment: Вы ведь делаете `Path.GetFileName(sourcefile[ee])`. Это вам возвращает название файла с расширением (`D:\Folder1\Folder2\File 1.txt` -> `File 1.txt`). Это не то что вам нужно?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну вот. Как же стыдно. Забыть этот базовый синтаксис.... Спасибо Вам. Поменяйте ваш комментарий на ответ, я отмечу. Спасибо. Хоть я сомневаюсь, что кому то это поможет.

Comment: Ну, я бы сказал что это вопрос "опечатка" или нечто такое, ибо вы говорите "хочу", "как?", а сами вон метод используете. Ценности в вопросе не вижу, поэтому и отвечать, пожалуй, не буду. Это можете сделать конечно вы сами, а еще лучше, найти дубликат (вроде был).

Comment: Я бы не додумался написать `Path.GetFilename`... Спасибо, еще раз

Comment: А [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7db6.png) видать я за вас написал, да?) Как же так, используете методы, даже не разобравшись в их функционале...

Comment: Все верно, учусь, практикуюсь. Виноват. Невнимателен. Я уже и Replace и Regex пробовал и Split